# Using multer cause error when running app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipart, multer

Im having node application with express which use multer module
https://github.com/expressjs/multer

in the `app.js` file I put the following:

```
var mulStorage = require("./utils/store"),
    var upload = multer({
        storage: mul.storage,
        dest: 'uploads/'
    });
    app.use(upload.single('file'));
```

The `store.js` file look like following

```
var multer = require('multer');

var stor = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var filename = file.originalname;
        var fileExtension = filename.split(".")[1];
        cb(null, Date.now() + "." + fileExtension);
    }
})
module.exports = {
    stor: stor
}
```

When I run request using postman I got the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'c:\Users\c45669\WebstormProjects\App\uploads\1454935327214.zip'
>   
>     at Error (native)

**Why multer doesn't create the folder if it doesn't exist??**

If I'm creating the upload folder under the root **manually** this is working...

BTW,
When I change the following and remove the `storage: mul.storage,`
This is working, but I need the storage to **determine the file name ...**

```
    var upload = multer({
        //storage: mul.storage,
        dest: 'uploads/'
    });
```

**Even If I remove the property dest from multer object and keep only the storage I got the same error...**

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, multer does not create the folder it should be created either manually or programmatically. Assuming that the uploads folder exist, is there any other that you are facing with uploads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why multer doesn't create the folder if it doesn't exist??

This is in documentation ([link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)) :

> Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you.

I don't know why the author made this decision, but as you see this is not a bug.

You can use `fs` module to create directories.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem if someone take the error i solved

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, file, cb) {
 cb(null, 'this is not just /uploads do it like /var/www/....') thank you!!
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
}
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```